How to best integrate ML models to web application?
I have no experience in ML and am a beginner in web application programming. I currently have a flask app that uses audiocraft and a classificatoin model. Currently i have these stored locally within the application folder. I have built an image of this app and it turned out to be 7GB.
Is there a way to have these models/ framework stored somewhere else and only referenced when I need them?
Also, when i run the container on docker, it takes around 10minuts to generate a 8s audio from audiocraft. What would you recommend I do to fasten the process?
music_generation\routes.py (snippet)
def load_model():
    model = MusicGen.get_pretrained('facebook/musicgen-small')
    return model

def generate_music_tensors(description, duration: int):
    model = load_model()
    model.set_generation_params(
        use_sampling=True,
        top_k=250,
        duration=duration
    )
    output = model.generate(
        descriptions=[description],
        progress=True,
        return_tokens=True
    )
    return output[0]

@music_generation_bp.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def generate_music():
    data = request.json

    description = data.get('description')
    duration = data.get('duration', 8)  # Default to 8 seconds if not provided
    print("Description:", description)
    print("Duration:", duration)

    if not description:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Description is required'}), 400
    # Generate unique key for the user
    user_id = str(uuid.uuid4())  # or use a user ID from your authentication system
    audio_key_prefix = f"generated_music_{user_id}_{description}"

    # Generate music tensors
    music_tensors = generate_music_tensors(description, duration)
    print("Music Tensors: ", music_tensors)
...


image_classification\routes.py  (snippet)
# Load the pre-trained model
model_path = os.path.join(MODELS_DIR, 'multi_output_model.h5')
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)

@image_classification_bp.route('/', methods=['POST'])
@limiter.limit("1/minute")
def classify_image():
     if 'file' not in request.files:
         return jsonify({"error": "No file part in the request"}), 400

     file = request.files['file']

     if file.filename == '':
         return jsonify({"error": "No selected file"}), 400

    #file = os.path.join(TEST_IMG_DIR, 'blue-dress2.png')

    if file:
        # Read the image file
        img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(file.read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (IMAGE_DIMS[1], IMAGE_DIMS[0]))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = preprocess_input(img)
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

        # Perform prediction
        predictions = model.predict(img)



You could mount the model as a volume rather than include it in the image

Normally, if you want to host a web application that can store large binary file, you would need a blob storage database. There are various enterprise solutions like AWS S3, Azure Blob Storage, Google Cloud that provides infrastructure to store your data that you can just load  to use when you needed. However, this might be a bit costly and also not too efficient when the model size is too large.
Another alternative that I can think of is having a separate running backend server that has readily access to the model and can accept incoming requests from the frontend server containing user input parameters and then use the input parameters to generate desired output as a response to frontend server request. That way, you don't need to load the model everytime users visit your web application route and instead forward the request to the server that already has the model loaded to handle the request. In docker terms, It would mean you need to create a separate image to load the model and handle frontend incoming requests and have its running container exposed to the image that is running the flask web application server so that it can forward requests and receive response from that container
